# PHP - Calling a function from another function from another class

Tags: php, class

I have 2 classes, one named ***site_navigation*** and the other named ***member_config***.

I have created a function in my site_navigation called getNavBar.

Inside this function, I try to get my users level from a function named userLevelValidation inside a different class called member_config.

This is my class for site_navigation :

```
class site_navigation {

function getNavBar() {
global $con;
$usersLevel = $member_config->userLevelValidation();
$page_link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if($usersLevel == "Administrator") { 
        ?>
            <li class="sidebar-heading"> <b><i>Seller</i></b> Tools</li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "members.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="members.php"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "mTokens.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="mTokens.php"> <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> <span>Redeem / My Tokens</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "mAccount.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="mAccount.php"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Manage My Account</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "mSupport.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="mSupport.php"> <i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> <span>Support</span></a></li>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-heading"> <b><i>Admin / Staff  </i></b> Tools</li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_dash.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_dash.php"> <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_members.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_members.php"> <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>Manage Clients</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_site.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_site.php"> <i class="fa fa-cogs"></i> <span>Manage Site</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_server.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_server.php"> <i class="fa fa-server"></i> <span>Manage Server</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_tokens.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_tokens.php"> <i class="fa fa-key"></i> <span>Manage Tokens</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_updates.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_updates.php"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Manage Updates</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_logs.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_logs.php"> <i class="fa fa-address-book"></i> <span>Logs</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_staff.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_staff.php"> <i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i> <span>Manage Staff</span></a></li>
            </li>
        <?php
    } else if($usersLevel == "Staff") {
            ?>
            <li class="sidebar-heading"> <b><i>User</i></b> Management</li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "members.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="members.php"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "mTokens.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="mTokens.php"> <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> <span>Redeem / My Tokens</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "mAccount.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="mAccount.php"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Manage My Account</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "mSupport.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="mSupport.php"> <i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> <span>Support</span></a></li>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-heading"> <b><i>Staff</i></b> Tools</li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_dash.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_dash.php"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_members.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_members.php"> Manage Clients</a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_tokens.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_tokens.php"> Manage Tokens</a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_updates.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_updates.php"> Manage Updates</a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "admin_support.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="admin_support.php"> Manage Support</a></li>
            </li>
        <?php
    } else if($usersLevel == "Seller") {
            ?>
            <li class="sidebar-heading"> <b><i>Seller</i></b> Tools</li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "members.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="members.php"> <i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "mTokens.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="mTokens.php"> <i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> <span>Redeem / My Tokens</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "mAccount.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="mAccount.php"> <i class="fa fa-user"></i> <span>Manage My Account</span></a></li>
                <li <?php if ($page_link == "mSupport.php") { echo "class='-active'";}?>><a href="mSupport.php"> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span>Support</span></a></li>
            </li>
        <?php
    }
  }
}

//Call the class function for site_config
$site_nav = new site_navigation();
```

And this is my class for my member_config :

```
class member_config {

function grabUserInfos()
{
    global $con;
    $username = $_SESSION["username"];
    $query    = "SELECT id, username, password, email, cpukey, salt, ip, time, titleid, enabled, kvdata, lastonline, profile_picture, userLevel, register_time, customlifetimenotify, gamertag FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result = $con->query($query) or die("Error");
    return $result->fetch_all();
}

function userLevelValidation()
{
    global $con;
    $users = $this->grabUserInfos();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $userLevel = $user[13];
        if ($userLevel == 3) {
            return "Administrator";
        } else if ($userLevel == 2) {
            return "Staff";
        } else if ($userLevel == 1) {
            return "Seller";
        } else
            return "Unknown";
    }
  }
}

//Call the class function for member_config
$member_config = new member_config();
```

How would I go about calling the `userLevelValidation();` inside my site_navigation class, inside the getNavBar function ?

I have tried putting this : `$usersLevel = $member_config->userLevelValidation();` but it says

```
Fatal Error: Call to a member function userLevelValidation() on null.
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php and you should look into dependency injection as well as you really should not use `global` for your database connection.

Comment: you've not initialized the class in `site_navigation` class or you can inherit the class. like making `class site_navigation extends member_config {` you must include the both class in main file or have both classes in main file.

Comment: Classes are at same file?

Comment: if the function needs what's in the othe class instance, you could pass the instace as parameter. It it is independant from instances, you can make it a static function

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari yes the classes are in the same file, underneath eachother.

Comment: @BenWilson Please check my answer

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari But you say that's for different files.

Comment: No problem, no need for include the other file

Comment: @BenWilson check my answer now without include any file the concept is the same.

Comment: As a general guideline, most classes use  a standard StudlyCaps, which would mean your classes would be called - MemberConfig and SiteNavigation.

Comment: Also it may be of interest to start looking into a templating library (i.e. Twig) which can do a lot of the composition of the HTML in a more secure and modular way.

Comment: @jeroen How else could I call my database connection more securely then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do as follow:

```
<?php

class test1
{
   private $name = 'Akbari';

   function getName()
   {
     return $this->name;
   }   
}


class test2
{

     function __construct()
     {
     }

     function callA()
     {
       $test1Object = new test1();
       $name = $test1Object->getName();
       echo $name;    //Prints Akbari
     }
}

//create an object
$test2Object = new test2();
$test2Object->callA();
?>
```

Comment: brilliant! Works perfectly in this format. I just needed to re add in `$member_conf = new member_config();`